# Attribute to find out a virtual instance private only or public and private

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can we find out a VM has public and private IP or only private IP? Is there any particular attribute in the JSON response for  a virtual guest request?

Answer (score 0):

Sure take a look at documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

primaryBackendIpAddress
A guest's primary private IP address.
Type: string
primaryIpAddress
The guest's primary public IP address.
Type: string

if you do not see any value for any of those properties that means that the virtual guest does not have it.

Regards